# How to export a 'posed' mesh as an STL file

Tags: export

I'm new to Blender and am trying to export a mesh that I've manipulated with an armature, as an STL file. It will export as stl in the 'rest' position, but when I pose it, then export as STL, then try to open STL file in other software, there is nothing. Is it possible to do this, or will it only export in the rest position?

Comment: In export window select apply modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured out that after I pose the object, I then need to convert it back into a mesh. Then it will export as an stl file. I selected the object in 'object mode', in the object menu selected 'Convert to -> Mesh from surface....'

(I tried 'apply modifiers' but it didn't seem to work for me)